# How to read the full length of modbus RTU holding registers (Add 40001 : 49999)?

Tags: modbus

I'm using J2mod to communicate with HW over Modbus RTU and my scope is to read holding registers from address 40001 to 49999.
The problem is the Modbus frame max no of registers is 125 / request.
and i want to read almost 10000 registers, how to apply this because if i will apply for loop each loop reads only 125 registers then to complete the full scan cycle the time will be too too long.

so what is the best practices for this case?

Regards
Hani

Comment: There is no way to read that many registers (in Modbus RTU) without looping.   Why so many registers?  I have never seen a Modbus device with that many registers.  We have devices with a couple hundred registers, but in most cases the end user is only interested in a small subset of those.

Comment: I have to use the full length of registers because i need to read all the internal memory of PLC without exceptions,  so what will be the best practice for this.

Comment: The only way to do it is in a loop.   Even if you could write custom Modbus functions on the PLC, the spec limits the ADU to 256 bytes; the PDU is limited to 253 bytes (ADU - address - CRC); and the payload/data is limited to 252 bytes (PDU - function code).